# Active reports 11 set unknown control text value using variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, activereports

I am using Active Reports 11 in Visual Studio 2017. I need to populate a table of controls that is a group header section of the report. I am using an unbound datasource. Is it possible to set the value of a control by passing in the control name via a variable? If so how? I attempted the below strategy however Text is not a property of Controls.

```cs
this.FirstPage.Controls[fieldName].Text = "field text";
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a SectionReport and to set the Text of a TextBox placed in the GroupHeader section, you can handle the GroupHeader section's Format event and set the Text as follows:

```
private void ghOrderID_Format(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TextBox1.Text = "field Text";
}
```